# With 'height: 0;' on parent, child element is invisible, but still there?

Tags: css

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/BqMcD/) which shows a sample menu that I've written.

This is how it looks untouched:

[image: screenshot]

...when mouse is hovered on a menu:

[image: screenshot]

...when mouse is hovered near the white space right below the "Search" menu (Look at the "Search" menu closely. The search icon should be white. It's black because the mouse is, in a way, hovered on the menu item which is hidden):

[image: screenshot]

That's the `form` element residing in a `div` whose `height` is `0px` at the moment (becomes `height: auto;` dynamically when the menu is clicked, revealing the menu item i.e. the form).

[image: screenshot]

I have tried `overflow: hidden;` on the parent `div` to no avail. I can think of no other options. How can I fix this (with CSS)?

***EDIT:** Fixed image links in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/BqMcD/). Issue persists only in Chrome. Everything's fine in Firefox. No idea why.*

Comment: I don't see any issue here

Comment: @Mr.Alien Look at the third image closely. The search `icon` should be white. It's black because the mouse is, in a way, `hovered` on the menu item. Get the idea of what I am trying to say? **EDIT:** edited question for the sake of clarity.

Comment: You forgot to change the icon image URLs to imgur links within the fiddle, so they're not showing up.

Comment: @BoltClock Are you sure? It's working fine here.

Comment: @its_me images are missing dude

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://i.imgur.com/UaRHW.png

Comment: @BoltClock My apologies. I thought you were referring to the other images as the imgur images were loading just fine on my end. Fixed the fiddle in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why that weird thing is happening, but I believe it shouldn't. There's a temporary fix, though:

```
.menu-item > a:hover > [class*="icon-"],
.menu-item > a:hover > [class*=" icon-"],
.menu-item > a.selected > [class*="icon-"],
.menu-item > a.selected > [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: url(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/JeSdE/2/) with the fix.

***NOTE:** It would nevertheless be great if someone could explain why the issue presented in the question is at all happening.*